# React Native: function called in Render, running in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my code :

```js
 "use strict";

import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { Actions, ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux';


var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage');
var DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

var LOADING = {};
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "oc.db", location: 'default'});
class Profile extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users: [],
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
              rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
            }),
        };

    }

    fetch(){
      console.log('fetching data from database');
      //////
      var query = "SELECT * FROM users";
      var params = [];
      var userlist = [];
      db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(query,params, (tx, results) => {
                var len = results.rows.length;
                for(var ind = 0; ind < len; ind++ ){
                  userlist[ind] = {
                    userId: results.rows.item(ind).userId,
                    userName: results.rows.item(ind).userName,
                    userMail: results.rows.item(ind).userMail,
                    active: results.rows.item(ind).active
                  };
                }
                this.setState({
                  users: userlist,
                });
              }, function(){
                console.log('Profile: Something went wrong');
              });
          });

      //////////
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetch();
  }

  activate(uid){
    console.log('Lets de-activate all accounts');
    var query = "UPDATE users SET active='no' WHERE active=?";
    var params = ['yes'];
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(query,params, (tx, results) => {
        console.log('all users should be de-active now');
        console.log('activating user ', uid);
        var query = "UPDATE users SET active='yes' WHERE userId=? LIMIT 1;";
        var params = [uid];
        db.transaction((tx) => {
          tx.executeSql(query,params, (tx, results) => {
            console.log('UserId ' , uid , ' is Active now');
            this.renderUsers();
            //Actions.bridge({type: 'reset', toGo: 'home'});
          }, function(){
            console.log('No such a user found to make active');
          });
        });
      }, function(){
        console.log('No such a user found to make active');
      });
    });
  }

  resetNav(){
    Actions.bridge({type: 'reset'});
  }

  renderUsers(){
    console.log('Rendering Users');
    //this.fetch();
    var ulist = this.state.users;
    var urow = [];
    for(let a=0; a < ulist.length; a++){
      let active = ulist[a].active === 'yes' ? '◉' : '◯';
      let usid = ulist[a].userId;
      urow.push(
        <TouchableOpacity key={a} onPress={() => { this.activate(usid); /* this.resetNav(); */ }} style={styles.uitem}>
          <Text style={styles.uText}>{ulist[a].userName} {ulist[a].userMail}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.uTextAct}>{active}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
    return(
      <View style={styles.ulist}>{urow}</View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.pic}>
      <Icon name="ios-person" color="#00a2dd" size={180}></Icon>
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.heading}>
        Welcome to your Profile page!{'\n'}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.listtitle}>Users List</Text>
      <Text style={styles.listdesc}>To switch between accounts, simply click on them.</Text>
      {this.renderUsers()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Results are shown, it's working. but problem is renderUsers() is running in a loop. it's being called forever. where am i wrong? any solutions please?

---

Update :
When i put this.fetch to renderUsers() , it's fine. when you select a user, it will be active and you can see the list is updating. but problem is list being updated in a loop. it's happening ever and ever again.

when i put this.fetch to componentdidmount , the loop problem is fixed, but when you change active user, list is not being updated.

Comment: What is `this.fetch()` doing? If it's using `this.setState({...})`, then it will re-render every time it does which is likely the problem

Comment: this.fetch() gets data with fetch from remote server and saves it in this.setState({...}) . that's the problem? any solutions?

Comment: do `this.fetch` in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: i was doing that. but the problem was, when the users was changing something in the component, it was not reloading(refreshing) so i did like that.

Comment: in profile page, there are few users , you can select which user to be active, when you select the user, user will be active, but component still showing old data ( old account as active ) so, i moved this.fetch from componentwillmount to render itself

Comment: how about using componentWillReceiveProps or componentWillUpdate in addition to componentDidmount? Not sure, but i think this could help. Maybe u can add this.fetch() to your onPress with an small timeout and than update/fetch your data as soon as u clicked the button.

Comment: do you mean componentwillreceiveprops? i didnt know about componentWillReceive

Comment: Whoops, yes i just updated my comment

Comment: @casraf , i have updated the question with whole code.

Comment: @BigPun86 i tried adding this.fetch to componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps but no lock.
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetch();
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.fetch();
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. in activate function, i added the Actions.refresh method from router-flux and i added this.setState in componentwillreceiveprops. now it's working as expected. final code is like this :

changes :

```js
////Added this code :
componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.fetch();
    this.setState({
      somekey: 'yes'
    });
  }

/// Added Actions.refresh({somekey: 'Yes'}); with some random props
activate(uid){
    console.log('Lets de-activate all accounts');
    var query = "UPDATE users SET active='no' WHERE active=?";
    var params = ['yes'];
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(query,params, (tx, results) => {
        console.log('all users should be de-active now');
        console.log('activating user ', uid);
        var query = "UPDATE users SET active='yes' WHERE userId=? LIMIT 1;";
        var params = [uid];
        db.transaction((tx) => {
          tx.executeSql(query,params, (tx, results) => {
            console.log('UserId ' , uid , ' is Active now');
            this.renderUsers();
            Actions.refresh({somekey: 'yes'});
            //Actions.bridge({type: 'reset', toGo: 'home'});
          }, function(){
            console.log('No such a user found to make active');
          });
        });
      }, function(){
        console.log('No such a user found to make active');
      });
    });
  }
```

Hope it will help others who have the same issue

Comment: I think you could just put `this.fetch()` in `componentDidMount` and when the user makes changes call it again. But if this works as expected might be good too

Comment: @casraf actually i did that, since i was setting state inside this.fetch, that was executing in a loop.

Comment: re-render shouldn't call componentDidMount another time, so that's odd...